# How to install drivers on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers

Fair warning, I am new to Ubuntu (coming from windows), so you may have to dumb some things down. 
I got a desktop for christmas. It is a pre-built used desktop. It has absolutely no drivers on it currently. I actually somehow managed to get minecraft working, but then I realized the graphics were horrible! I also have no sound. I googled and googled so that I could figure what the heck graphics card I have and came up with this info

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Barts XT [Radeon HD 6870]
```

Now, I have googled and googled to figure how to get the drivers for it, to no avail. I did find somewhere that told me to look in the additional drivers but the only thing is there is Unknown: Unknown. I am scratching my head and going nuts trying to figure this all out. If you need additional info, you will probably need to tell me how to find it.

Comment: There is no additional driver for Radeon HD 6870, however, the official standard kernel driver should be loaded. It is called "radeon".  So, to address your worries about "no drivers on it currently", open a terminal window and run `lspci -nnk`. You should see a printout of some of the hardware with drivers used.

Comment: You are already using all the drivers you need. Linux comes with generic drivers by default. Only if there are 3rd party drivers you can exchange your generic driver for the 3rd party (and those tend to be for your video card and your NIC). Linux is not Windows where you need to install drivers for any piece of hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Open **Software & Updates**, then open **Additional Drivers** tab and install needed drivers from here.

Comment: The only thing that shows up in the additional drivers tab is unknown: unknown. It doesn't know what it is, and neither do I

Comment: I assumed that these drivers are installed from here. I do not have AMD video card. Let's wait for other answers.

Comment: @N0rbert Could "unknown" be the Intel Microcode driver? In which case it  should usually be installed.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix seems to be intel microcode. My modern Ivy Bridge laptop has microcode in this section.